# Ejecutar Servlet Intellij

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea

Hola chicos soy nuevo en esto de los Servlets y estoy probando como implementar alguno asi sencillo pero estoy teniendo un problema, os comento.

Estoy usando el editor Intellij para la implementacion del mismo. Tengo todo implementado: la clase index.jsp y una clase .java con el metodo DoGet que me tendria que ejcutar un codigo html super simple pero no me funciona, os mando el codigo que tengo y el error que me da (Todo compila sin problema)

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registro</title>
</head>
<header class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Prueba Servlet</h1>
</header>
<body>

<form action="Servlet" method="post">

    <label>Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre"
           placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Servlet.java**

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try{
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servidor</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Hola amigo: "+request.getParameter("nombre")+"</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

La idea es que al darle al boton de enviar me diga HOLA y el nombre que haya puesto pero me da el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto sale en Intellij como veis esta todo correcto por eso no se que es lo que me esta fallando :((

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno sabe por que falla?? Muchas gracias

Comment: En tu codigo `<form action="Servlet" method="post">` no tienes que poner la extension del archivo servlet? en este caso .java. Deberia ser `<form action="Servlet.java" method="post">`

Comment: Que vaa, ya lo he probado y me sigue saliendo el mismo error :((

Comment: Quizas como tu archivo .java esta en otra carpeta distinta de donde esta tu archivo jsp, tendrás que poner en el action, la ruta apuntado a tu carpeta/archivo.java

Comment: Ya he probado tambien a cambiarlo y poner la ruta completa y nada no se que mas hacer. Acabo de cambiar el directorio root y lo he puesto al del proyecto y nada sigue igual...